# Deserializing embedded array/list to array in c# as expandoobject

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jint

I have JSON objects having embedded arrays - with no predefined strongly typed class to deserialize to. ExpandoObject deserialization with Json.Net works, but the array is deserialized to list, which is an issue for me. I need expndoobject with arrays. Is there any setting I could use with Json.NET to achieve this?

Example:

```
var obj = """
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 18,
    "grid": [
        {
            "type": "A",
            "price": 13
        },
        {
            "type": "B",
            "price": 1
        },
        {
            "type": "A",
            "price": 17
        }
    ]
}
""";

var engine = new Engine()
   .Execute("function eval(value) { return value.grid.filter((it)=>it.type === 'A').map(it=>it.price).reduce((a,b)=>a+b) }");

dynamic v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(obj, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

engine.Invoke("eval", v);
```

Where this library is used: https://github.com/sebastienros/jint
Result:

[image]

And I need an array there, or otherwise the call fails ("Property 'filter' of object is not a function").

Using `dynamic v= Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(obj);` I got this:

[image]

And still fails with: "Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "filter". Int32 array index expected."

If I define classes for this sample:

```
class Inner
{ 
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

class X
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Inner[] Grid { get; set; }
}
```

it is parsed just fine (`var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<X>(obj);`) and the code returns what I am expecting. Not so when I use `List<Inner>` instead of the array. Hence the problem is that it is not an array.
So I am looking for any solution that results in an array at that position.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250295/discussion-on-question-by-zorgoz-deserializing-embedded-array-list-to-array-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

why don't try something like this

```
Inner[] inners = JObject.Parse(obj).Properties()
            .Where( p=> p.Value.Type== JTokenType.Array)
            .SelectMany(p => p.Value.ToObject<Inner[]>())
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: It's not the data. The OP is trying to use a beta version that keeps changing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am sorry but I don't understand why to use something very complilcated that will never work properly, instead of using a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Jint issue. The latest stable version won't even parse the JS function. The following code, using the latest stable 2.11.58, throws without any data:

```
using Jint;

var js = """
    function eval(value) { 
        return value.grid.filter((it) => it.type === 'A')
                         .map(it => it.price)
                         .reduce((a,b)=>a+b) 
    }
    """;

var engine = new Engine().Execute(js);
```

This throws

```
Jint.Parser.ParserException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Line 2: Unexpected token >
  Source=Jint
  StackTrace:
   at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ThrowError(Token token, String messageFormat, Object[] arguments)
   at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ThrowUnexpected(Token token)
   at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParsePrimaryExpression()
   at Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall()
...
```

The latest stable doesn't understand arrow functions to begin with.

The latest 3.0 beta, `3.0.0-beta-2044` can parse this but throws with a *different* error than the one in the question. I guess the latest beta has progressed a bit. This time `filter` is recognized but it doesn't work yet.

Invoking the function with data

```
var obj = """
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 18,
    "grid": [
        {
            "type": "A",
            "price": 13
        },
        {
            "type": "B",
            "price": 1
        },
        {
            "type": "A",
            "price": 17
        }
    ]
}
""";

dynamic v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(obj);

engine.Invoke("eval", v);
```

throws

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "filter". Int32 array index expected.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json
  StackTrace:
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.get_Item(Object key)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Jint.Runtime.ExceptionHelper.ThrowMeaningfulException(Engine engine, TargetInvocationException exception)
   at Jint.Runtime.Interop.Reflection.ReflectionAccessor.GetValue(Engine engine, Object target)
   at Jint.Runtime.Descriptors.Specialized.ReflectionDescriptor.get_CustomValue()
...
```

In this case, Jint tried to use `filter` as an index value for `grid`.

Array access *does* work though, so it's not JArray that's causing the problem.

This JS function :

```
var js = """
    function eval(value) { 
        return value.grid[0].type 
    }
    """;
```

Works and returns `A`

Comment: preview-385 evaluates it correctly if that list is array

Comment: The latest is `beta-2044`. It returns a different error. You're arguing about beta software.

Comment: You don't get my point. I have no problem with the JS part. I can get rid of lambdas if needed.

Comment: You're arguing about a bug in *beta software* that no longer returns the error you mentioned. If you try `value.grid[0].type` you'll get `A`. You should open a Github Issue in the JInt repo

Answer (score 0):

I have created a modified version of the original ExpandoObjectConverter. And that works.

```
public static class _
{
    public static bool MoveToContent(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        JsonToken tokenType = reader.TokenType;
        while (tokenType == JsonToken.None || tokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
        {
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                return false;
            }
            tokenType = reader.TokenType;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static bool IsPrimitiveToken(this JsonToken token)
    {
        if ((uint)(token - 7) <= 5u || (uint)(token - 16) <= 1u)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


public class MyExpandoObjectConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // can write is set to false
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="JsonReader"/> to read from.</param>
        /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
        /// <param name="existingValue">The existing value of object being read.</param>
        /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
        /// <returns>The object value.</returns>
        public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return ReadValue(reader);
        }

        private object? ReadValue(JsonReader reader)
        {
            if (!reader.MoveToContent())
            {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
            }

            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    return ReadObject(reader);
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                    return ReadList(reader);
                default:
                    if (reader.TokenType.IsPrimitiveToken())
                    {
                        return reader.Value;
                    }

                    throw new Exception($"Unexpected token when converting ExpandoObject: {reader.TokenType}");
            }
        }

        private object ReadList(JsonReader reader)
        {
            IList<object?> list = new List<object?>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.Comment:
                        break;
                    default:
                        object? v = ReadValue(reader);

                        list.Add(v);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.EndArray:
                        return list.ToArray();
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
        }

        private object ReadObject(JsonReader reader)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object?> expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                        string propertyName = reader.Value!.ToString()!;

                        if (!reader.Read())
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
                        }

                        object? v = ReadValue(reader);

                        expandoObject[propertyName] = v;
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.Comment:
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.EndObject:
                        return expandoObject;
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether this instance can convert the specified object type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if this instance can convert the specified object type; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return (objectType == typeof(ExpandoObject));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can write JSON.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///     <c>true</c> if this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can write JSON; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>
        public override bool CanWrite => false;
    }

....
dynamic v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(obj, new MyExpandoObjectConverter());
```

Yes, I am aware, that the JS engine part might change, as this is beta. However, my JS function is perfectly valid. I don't really expect the engine to be worse in compatibility with the standards and not better. But my error was not related to that. I simply asked for a solution to deserialize to an array instead of a list.

Comment: Not really - it bypasses the Jint bug in the version you used. This bug has already changed. What happens with the current beta? What about next month when a new beta is released?

Comment: Frankly, if you intend to write so much code why not deserialize to specific types? It's less code and less error prone than this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as I stated at the beginning, neither the object nor the function that evaluates is something I can predict. 
I am not bypassing any bugs right now. This is how it should behave if conforming with JS standards. Yes, the code might introduce new bugs later on, as any code can.
But this is why we don't update referenced libraries blindly...